# linux(Ubuntu) equivalent of windows' mongod command

Tags: mongodb

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux in general; I used to use Windows platforms for my entire life.

When I want to connect my apps to the mongodb database in Windows I had to initiate a mongo database in a separate CMD by running `mongod`. But that was not the case in Linux, all I had to do is just start the application and there was no need for `mongod` command. I am really wondering what is happing. Would you please help me understand the difference between Ubuntu and Winndows when using Mongodb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All platforms require a running MongoDB server process if you want to connect to a local server. The server binary is `mongod` on Linux/macOS or `mongod.exe` on Windows.

A main difference in installation experience (as at MongoDB 3.4) is that the Ubuntu packages for MongoDB will automatically create a service definition and start `mongod` after installation. The Ubuntu package also creates a data directory (`/var/lib/mongodb`) and configuration file used by the `mongod` service (`/etc/mongod.conf`).  This enables the `mongod` service to be [stopped](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#stop-mongodb), [started](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#start-mongodb), and [restarted](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#restart-mongodb) using  standard Ubuntu service management commands.

On Windows you can [configure a Windows Service definition](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb-community-edition) to start the MongoDB server as a background service, but this is not currently done by the standard Windows installer. Most tutorials assume that Windows users will not have a service definition and suggest manually starting `mongod.exe` in a CMD window.

One other difference in Linux vs Windows versions of the MongoDB server is that Linux `mongod` binaries include an option to `--fork` and run the server process in the background. The Windows API does not support the same concept of [forking processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork%E2%80%93exec), so if you are starting a server manually you need to open one CMD window for `mongod.exe` and a second CMD window for interacting via the `mongo` shell or a command line client.

For production MongoDB deployments the most typical approach is to manage the MongoDB server using a service manager (regardless of platform). Using a service manager ensures that you start your MongoDB server with consistent configuration options and permissions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. It's all clear now!